# Cuckoo Sandbox - Unable to enable internet access via hostonly & iptables

Tags: defense

I'm having some issues with my deployment of the Cuckoo Sandbox.  I have been unable to enable internet access for the VM via the hostonlyif, *vboxnet0* and IPtables rules.

Here are some details regarding my configuration:

- Host - Ubuntu 16.04LTS;
- Host - hostonlyif (vboxnet0) is 192.168.56.1;
- Guest - WindowsXP SP3;
- Guest IP - Static at 192.168.56.19;

I can ping from Guest to Host and vice versa successfully.  I am using the following IPtables commands, which are straight from the Cuckoo virtual networking documentation:

```
    iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

I am using *iptables-save* and *iptables-restore* commands to ensure I can reapply the rules after reboot.

All the documentation says that this should work, however, I am still unable to connect to the internet.

I have added a second adaptor using the bridged mode and was able to access the internet just fine, although Cuckoo didn't seem to want to use it, even after I edited the configuration files.

Does anyone have a clue as to how I might resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iptables should really work.

Some more ideas:

1. You should check if the guest is really configured to use 192.168.56.1 as a gateway.
2. You should check your overall forwarding settings in the kernel to see whether it is not disabled for your `vboxnet0` interface or overall:

   ```
   $ sysctl -a |grep -e '\.forwarding'
   ```

Comment: Hi Michal - Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I booted my Ubuntu host, restored the iptables, logged into the WinXP guest and took a shot in the dark by loading IE.

Comment: (Accidentally hit enter).  Suffice to say, the guest now seems to be able to access the internet, although for reasons I don't understand.  I've been at this for weeks, pulling my hair out until someone suggested here and now I just feel like an amateur.  Thank you for your time - I'll see if I can't close this off now.

Comment: @MichalAmbroz - I've edited your comment-answer into a more-or-less full answer (e.g. removed all the "please post X" sentences).  But really, asking for more info should be done as a comment (and you already have enough rep to add comments).